# Spring transaction does not start

Tags: spring, transactions, spring-transactions

Environment: Eclipse Keppler, jetty 7.5.1, 
             Spring 3.2.1, Hibernate 4.2.5, Oracle 11

Problem: hibernate entity saves does not apply to database physically

Cause of problem may be: no active transaction

Question: Why does not transaction start?

Note: if I change openSession() to getCurrentSession(), everything works. Transaction starts & entity saves to DB physically.

---

GenericDaoImpl:

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, 
               value = "transactionManager")
public abstract class GenericDaoImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> implements GenericDao<T, ID> {

    private Class<T> persistentClass;   

    protected SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    @Override
    public T addEntity(T entity) {

        Session session = null;

        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            session.save(entity);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();    
        } finally {

            if(session != null){
                Transaction t = session.getTransaction();               
System.out.println("Transaction().isActive()......." + session.getTransaction().isActive());            
System.out.println("before: session.isOpen()  " + session.isOpen() + " trx wasCommitted " + t.wasCommitted());  

                session.close();

System.out.println("after: session.isOpen()  " + session.isOpen() + " trx  wasCommitted" + t.wasCommitted());               
        }
    }

    return entity;
}
```

UserDaoImpl extending GenericDaoImpl:

```
@Component
@Scope("prototype")
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false, value = "transactionManager")
public class UserDaoImpl extends GenericDaoImpl<User, Long> implements UserDao {
    .
    .
    }
```

After following code executed called:

```
userDao.addEntity(user);
```

logs printed below:

```
Transaction().isActive().......false
before: session.isOpen()  true trx wasCommitted false
after: session.isOpen()  false trx  wasCommittedfalse
```

transaction logs:

```
[2016-07-15 10:42:04,567][DEBUG] Adding transactional method 'addEntity' with attribute: PROPAGATION_REQUIRED,ISOLATION_DEFAULT; 'transactionManager'
```

databaseContext.xml:

```
<bean class="com.blabla.dao.local.implementations.UserDaoImpl"
    scope="prototype" name="userDao">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven />

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="packagesToScan"
        value="com.blabla.model.local,com.blabla.model.authorization, com.blabla.model.authentication" />
    <property name="entityInterceptor">
        <bean class="com.blabla.listeners.EntityInterceptor" />
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.transaction.flush_before_completion">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.HashtableCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.driver_class">${jdbc.driver}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.url">${jdbc.url}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.username">${jdbc.user}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.connection.password">${jdbc.password}</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="10" />
</bean>
```

Comment: while injecting sessionFactory object to your userDaoImpl you should not use scope as prototype in that case spring will creates new sessionFactory obj per each new call. sessionFactory obj must be one per application

Comment: The problem is that you don't use `getCurrentSession` which is what you should use else it won't work. You shouldn't be messing around with opening/closing sessions yourself, if you do that you also have to manage the transactions yourself.

Comment: You are trying to inject the sessionFactory object in your userDaoImpl class instead you should inject it directly into your generic class either using annotation or xml mapping.

Comment: @M. Deinum please tell me that he is injecting the sessionFactory obj into userDaoImpl class with prototype as scope then trying to access in generic class, how will this possible?

Comment: Assuming the `setSessionFactory` is on the generic dao he is injecting the thing perfectly fine. Also the fact that the bean that receives the session factory is prototype scoped doesn't affect anything at all.

Comment: @tinku It is as Deinum explained.Sınce it is inherited, the injection happens to GenericDao even if UserDao is stated in xml

Comment: @Deinum thanks for your explanation. I see it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example it's pretty much obvious that `spring` handles hibernate session and transaction:

```
<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

So you cannot use this:

```
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
```

Because you are opening new hibernate session and spring does not know nothing about this.

Using: `sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()` means that `spring` will handle everything behind the scene with your proper configuration.